# Python 2.7 on OS X(Sierra 10.12.5): TypeError:’frozenset' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12)

```
>>> import hashlib
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "build/bdist.macosx-10.12-intel/egg/hashlib.py", line 115, in <module>
        """
    TypeError: 'frozenset' object is not callable
    >>>
```

How can I fix this problem?